# Excluding specific OSGI-INF

Tags: java, osgi, aem, osgi-bundle, aem-6

I'm working on maven and OSGI based application and we are using OSGi R6 annotation in OSGi services.

We have a requirement to customise our application so that if we pass specific param during build time it excludes specific OSGi meta data information in target jar so that those specific will not appear in the configuration section.

Can anybody point out how we can solve this?

Comment: I doubt that this is your requirement. It is probably one possible solution. Can you describe why you want to remove the information? I guess there is a proper way to do this.

Comment: Actually our OSGi services divided into two sets and we have a use case if we build our codebase and pass some parameter during build so that it will only activate one set  of service and corresponding OSGi config and disable others.

Comment: For that, you should use run modes instead. You could probably find a way to do this at build time. But run modes would be far better for this use-case, especially that you can toggle them relatively easily (AEM restart required) additionally, you end up with one artifact, instead of 2 (or however many you were planning on building)

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, I understood your point but this is a development of a aem plugin so we need two separate artifacts which needs to be customised based on our build parameter.

Comment: I have achieved this using maven shade plugin which is being called on build parameter.

Comment: @Arpit Can you please add your solution to the answer section?